# How do I stop unnecessary re-renders of child component when the parent changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

So I currently have a component that looks like this:

```
<Parent>
<Child/>
</Parent>
```

However, sometimes I want to only return:
`<Child/>`

This could be done like this:

```
if (condition) {
return <Child/>
}

return (
<Parent>
<Child/>
</Parent>
)
```

The problem is when `condition` is met (true) `<Child/>` will re-render. It's a shame because none of the props/state inside `<Child/>` change and this component can be quite expensive to render.

I would prefer not to rewrite `<Parent/>` so that what is needed in it becomes a sibling to `<Child/>` as it's a big change.

How would I go about stopping this unnecessary render of `<Child/>` each time `condition` is met.

I have tried to use `React.memo` but it wasn't working how I expected.

Comment: Hi! What the logic of 'condition' changing?

Comment: How was your usage of `React.memo` not working how you expected? How did you try to use `React.memo`?

Comment: Can you just assign child to a variable? Like `const child = <Child />` and return it if `condition`, otherwise `<Parent>{ child }</Parent>`

Comment: The logic is a change in URL params. Which will occur on a menu item click.

When I have used useMemo (as suggested below) the re-renders continue. Honestly, I don't get why. For using React.memo, I am just wrapping the <Child/> component in memo(). However, the re-renders continue without changing of props.

And I do assign it to a variable, exactly as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried useMemo?

```
const child = useMemo(()=><Child/>,[])

if(condition) return child;

//...
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.

I tried this and am logging "rendered" inside components within <Child/> and they are being re-rendered when I change the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think what you're trying to achieve is possible, however you could do a workaround with similar functionality. Think about it like this: Instead of adding and removing the wrapper of the child (Parent), try to add and remove the siblings. It would be pretty much the same thing. I know you said that you'd like not to modify the code of `Parent` component, however I don't think this is going to affect your code.

Here's an example:

```
const Parent = ({
  children,
  state,
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
  state: number;
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {state % 2 === 0 ? (
        <>
          <label>Sibling 1</label>
          <div>Sibling 2</div>
        </>
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
      {children}
    </>
  );
};
```

As you can see, instead of modifying everything I just add and remove the siblings.
Also, remember to add useMemo to the child component:

```
const Child = () => {
  const [childState, setChildState] = useState<number>(0);

  return useMemo(() => {
    console.log("Child re-render");
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setChildState(childState + 1);
        }}
      >
        Child State: {childState}
      </button>
    );
  }, [childState]);
};
```

In this example, the child component should only re-render when childState is modified. If the state from the parent is modified, then only the siblings should be rendered. Here's my full code:

```
import { ReactNode, useMemo, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState<number>(0);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setAppState(appState + 1);
        }}
      >
        test
      </button>
      <Parent state={appState}>
        <Child />
      </Parent>
    </>
  );
};

const Parent = ({
  children,
  state,
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
  state: number;
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {state % 2 === 0 ? (
        <>
          <label>Sibling 1</label>
          <div>Sibling 2</div>
        </>
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

const Child = () => {
  const [childState, setChildState] = useState<number>(0);

  return useMemo(() => {
    console.log("Child re-render");
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setChildState(childState + 1);
        }}
      >
        Child State: {childState}
      </button>
    );
  }, [childState]);
};

export default App;
```

Comment: The problem is `<Parent/>` itself has a wrapper around `children`. If I try to render this conditionally I will run into the same problem as before but a bit lower in the tree.

Thank you for the response though!

I don't get why `useMemo` around <Child/> doesn't work.

Comment: well, I'm not completely sure how it works, however I think that useMemo stops working when you completely remove something, and since you remove the parent WITH the child and then you put the child back, the component needs to refresh. Basically useMemo only prevents re-renders from state change, however if you put a new instance of a component, then it has to refresh. How big is the wrapper? Maybe you could just modify its properties conditionally such that it's like it is not there. You could also render 2 components,one with the wrapper and one without and display: none one, a not good tho

Comment: It sounds like I'll need to do this or just hide the parent elements even if they're rendered.

I appreciate the time!